# Outlook 2010 does not remember settings of task view

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks

I have two questions about customizing Outlook 2010.

1. When clicking the "Tasks" shortcut in Outlook 2010 the default view opened is the "To-Do List". Can I set Outlook to open the Tasks view instead?
2. In the "Tasks" view I have switched off the navigation pane so that there is more space available for the actual content. Unfortunately Outlook does not remember this setting. Can I set this somewhere?

Thanks!